# java.lang.NumberFormatException when trying to Integer.parseInt a large string

Tags: java

I'm completely new to java (My second semester in cs, yet my first with java) And I've been solving some questions on codeforces and I came across one that wanted me to compare to large strings and print ">" , "<" , "=" depending on the result,It worked for most cases except when I entered a huge string like this
"1460175633701201615285047975806206470993708143873675499262156511814213451040881275819636625899967479"

The error I get is this :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1460175633701201615285047975806206470993708143873675499262156511814213451040881275819636625899967479"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at Qs.Compare.main(Compare.java:13)
```

Here Is My code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public static void main(String [] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
{
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    long n = Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());
    long m = Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());
    String fileName = "file";
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
         writer = new PrintWriter(fileName);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(n>m)
        writer.print(">");
    else
        if(n<m)
            writer.print("<");
        else
            if(n==m)
                writer.print("=");
    writer.close();

}
```

I tried using writer for the first time, But I was wondering Can i use System.out.print for this problem? (the question had instructed that it was not advisable) Sorry I know this is a really dumb question, But i'm new x.x Thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: use BigInteger instead of int/long

Comment: @Lashane Okay so it should be like `BigInteger n = BigInteger.parseInt(bf.readLine()); `  ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: I'll read it, thank you! :)

Comment: You understand that the `int` data type can only store numbers up to about 2 billion, right?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's giving the `NumberFormatException` exception is because the number you're trying to store into the `long` type is simply too large. Also, note that you were using `Integer.parseInt` rather than `Long.parseLong`(which in a way adds to the cause of the `NumberFormatException`). Other than that one minor mistake, given the `String` you're trying to parse, it would have thrown the same exception again even if you did use `Long.parseLong`.

you can accomplish your task with the use of [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

```
BigInteger n = new BigInteger(bf.readLine());
BigInteger m = new BigInteger(bf.readLine());

if (n.compareTo(m) < 0) {
     // do something
}else if(n.compareTo(m) > 0){
     // do something
}else{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is too bigger than Integer's length. You must find out the length of each data type before using it. Refer to [data type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)